# DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener failed in Lollipop version, any solution?

Tags: android

Month and Year spinner Dialog creation as

```
private DatePickerDialog createDialogWithoutDateField() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int monthOfYear = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dayOfMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this, DatePickerDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT, monthSetListener, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

        LinearLayout pickerParentLayout = (LinearLayout) dpd.getDatePicker().getChildAt(0);
        LinearLayout pickerSpinnersHolder = (LinearLayout) pickerParentLayout.getChildAt(0); // first child
        NumberPicker picker = (NumberPicker) pickerSpinnersHolder.getChildAt(0);
        picker.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        return dpd;
    }
```

Listener declare as

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener monthSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            Log.d("result", " month: " + selectedMonth + " year: " + selectedYear);
        }
    };
```

The log output is not working on the change of the month spinner or year spinner. Any Idea?

Comment: your code is working fine how you are using it ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Android code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/DatePickerDialog.java#171) the [`OnDateSetListener`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/DatePickerDialog.java#234)'s method:

```
void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth);
```

is called only, when positive button of `DatePickerDialog` is clicked.

What you might do is to get reference to every `NumberPicker` inside `DatePickerDialog` (just as you get it to hide the hour picker) and set [`OnValueChangeListener`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/NumberPicker.java#494) of it and do what you want inside listener's method:

```
void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

Implement the following interface in your activity 
`DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener`.

**Step 2:**

Then you will get an `override` method

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
}
```

**Step 3:**

Use the following method to show the popup ,

```
private void loadCalendar() {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    DatePickerDialog df = new DatePickerDialog(OptionCalculator.this, this, year, month, day);
    df.show();
}
```

It will work fine. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Android 5.0 and up that occurs when the datepicker is in its new material style calendar mode.
You can work around this bug by forcing the datepicker to use the pre-5.0 spinner mode by setting `android:datePickerMode="spinner"` on the DatePicker.

Or you can use the [DatePickerDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html) instead. The `onDateChanged` method of the dialog's listener does get called, even if the dialog is in the new material calendar mode.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that will work out.

```
final Calendar mcurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        int mYear = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mMonth = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int mDay = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(
                MainActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker,
                                  int selectedyear, int selectedmonth,
                                  int selectedday) {

                mcurrentDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, selectedyear);
                mcurrentDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, selectedmonth);
                mcurrentDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,
                        selectedday);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "MMM dd, yyyy",
                        Locale.US);


                edtTxtDOB.setText(sdf.format(mcurrentDate
                        .getTime()));
            }
        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

        mDatePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
        mDatePicker.show();
```